# Google developer account (Publisher)

Tags: android, publisher

I was just looking through to create a developer publisher account for Google and I came across that I need to pay $25 fee.

IS it possible to create a developer account for free e.g. for students, teachers... like with Microsoft developer account.

If not, is the $25 fee, one time or do I need to pay for every app I upload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Google site

> There is a one time $25 registration fee charged for a Google Play
>   Developer Console account. We charge this fee to encourage higher
>   quality products on Google Play (ie. less products with SPAM).

[here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113468?hl=en). So no, you'll pay it only one time and then publish as many apps as you want.

Comment: Is there any way of getting it for free if your a student or teacher?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible. (and I'm doing more research, and it still looks impossible)

Comment: I need to wait 10 minutes to accept the answer as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You only **pay once** for all the apps you upload and you can even share this account by giving permission to other Google accounts to upload apps.